# How to use psql CASE WHEN to test regular expressions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

The next function I wrote tries to return the same mcode if `split_part(mcode, ':', 2)` starts with F or returns something like N43452 if `split_part(mcode, ':', 2)` is just a number. I am trying to use the regular expression operator ~. I could do this using IF THEN but I am trying to use CASE WHEN. Any ideas where I am making a mistake?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getCode(mcode TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    CASE split_part(mcode, ':', 2)
        WHEN  (~ '^F')      THEN RETURN mcode
        WHEN  (~ '[0-9]+$') THEN RETURN CONCAT('N', mcode)
        ELSE RETURN mcode
    END;    


END;
$$;
```

I also tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getCode(mcode TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$
BEGIN
     CASE WHEN  (split_part(mcode, ':', 2) ~ '^F')      THEN RETURN mcode
          WHEN  (split_part(mcode, ':', 2) ~ '[0-9]+$') THEN RETURN CONCAT('N', mcode)
          ELSE RETURN mcode
     END;    
 
END;
$$;
```

Got the message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHEN"
          WHEN  (split_part(mcode, ':', 2) ~ '[0-9]+$') THEN ...
                 ^
```

Comment: `CASE … WHEN` uses equality, not some custom comparison or regex tests. You really want `CASE WHEN …` (or `IF … THEN`).

Comment: Bergi is correct. Try something like `s := split_part(mcode, ':', 2); CASE WHEN s ~ '^F' THEN ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how you do it ,
case  when .. only works for equation. also you need to put return once before case statement and you are done.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getCode(mcode TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$
BEGIN
   return 
    CASE WHEN split_part(mcode, ':', 2) ~ '^F' THEN  mcode
         WHEN split_part(mcode, ':', 2)  ~ '[0-9]+$' THEN  CONCAT('N', mcode)
        ELSE  mcode
    END;    
END;
$$;
```